# amp-html animation on scroll with position observer

Tags: animation, amp-html

I have a `<div>` in an `amp-project` (the header of the page) and I like these things happen to it:

1- on scroll down -> the div animates up and out of the view
2- on scroll up   -> the div animates down and into the view

I know I have to mix up `amp-animation` and `position-observer` but I can't find a proper tutorial in `amp site`.

Comment: Have you tried this [Animate Based On Visibility](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-position-observer#example:-animation-starts-and-pauses-based-on-visibility) ?